# How to match a substring between two record values in PosgreSQL?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, match, where-clause

I am looking for a solution to match two hidden strings in PostgreSQL. One record's value is a substring, the second is a text to match with. The code idea looks like this:

```
SELECT text_1, text_2
FROM texts
WHERE text_1 SIMILAR TO text_2;
```

The preferred output would be like this:

```
text_1, text_2
______________
foo_, foo_bar
sta, stack
love, ilove2code
```

The best analogue of Python:

```
if text_1 in text_2: ...
```

Comment: Simply `where text_2 like '%' || text_1 || '%'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get behavior the most similar to python's `in` syntax is to use strpos:

```
SELECT text_1, text_2
FROM texts
WHERE strpos(text_2, text_1) > 0;
```

The problem with using text_2 like '%' || text_1 || '%' or text_2 ~ text_1 or similar pattern matching is that you would have to ensure that your patterns don't contain any special characters that would influence the matching.

[Here's a fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kX22qBhxroPC3indWkc7d6/0) that demonstrates the solution and the problems with the others.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pg_trgm extension of postgresql.

[pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html)-
here you can easily find the similarity function **<->**.

you can use it like

text1 <-> text2